# REST method for altering state of sub resources

Tags: json, rest, http

Currently I have a REST API that represents a resource that has two different sub resources : errors with the resource and valid entries. Previously this structure was immutable : if you had an error it would stay an error and if you had valid entries they would stay as valid entries. As an example below is a sample JSON output :

```
GET /resource/1
{
  "resourceId" : 1,
  "errors" : [ 
    { "id": 1, "errorDetails" : "it isn't right" } 
  ],
  "validData" : [
    { "id": 1, "message" : "it's good!" }
  ]
}
```

Requirements have arise to allow correction of errors to make them valid. So in essence the result after the operation would be

```
GET /resource/1
{
  "resourceId" : 1,
  "errors" : [],
  "validData" : [
    { "id": 1, "message" : "it's good!" },
    { "id": 2, "message" : "Corrected, old data was : it isn't right" }
  ]
}
```

The correction process would take some extra parameters then either a) create a new error entry as the supplied parameters didn't correct the error or b) create a new valid entry as the error has been corrected.

From a REST perspective what is the best way to represent this?
So far I have the following ideas :

1. Have a PUT / DELETE on the errors i.e. PUT /resource/1/errors/1 with the parameters. This will cause a new sub-resource to be created under /resources/1/errors or /resources/1/validDate
2. Have a PUT on the root resource i.e. PUT /resource/1 with a reference to the error as you're modifying the resource as a whole by moving from one side to the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with option 1 and make the errors resources themselves, since they mean something and have some behavior as well (checking whether they can be removed). It should be a `POST` though, since it is some processing on server side necessary (if I understand that currectly) to determine what actually will be done.

Everything that is somehow "important" should be a resource, so option 2 seems sub-optimal.

Minor note: Everything that already has an id *probably* should be a resource, that is true for the "data" too. Also, unless there is a really good reason to explicitly leak the Ids of these things, I would rather give back the URIs to these things instead of the Ids.

Comment: The issue I see with option 1 is that by editing an 'error' resource you're potentially creating another 'error' or 'validData' resource. So POSTing to 'error' doesn't reflect that you're changing some other part of the resource.

Comment: I see, I thought you are correct the error, but you may be correcting the 'resource' itself, whatever that is. If you are correcting the resource, then I would `POST` to the resource itself. In this case however there should be no reference to the error, since those are then calculated again. Either case can result in more than one new entries, that is explicitly allowed for `POST`.